# How to disable any HTML element so it won't be handled by any event, similar to input element being disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When an `input` element is disabled, it won't be handled by any event.

```html
<input disabled />
```

How to achieve that for any element (e.g. a `span` element)?

I've tried using `pointer-events: "none"` but it only prevents click events. Other event such as `onKeyDown` can still be called.

Here is an example :

```js
import * as React from "react";

export default function UnstyledSwitches() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span tabIndex={0} onKeyDown={() => console.log("clicked")}>
        test
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/base-cra-typescript-forked-43708i?file=/src/App.tsx

Focus on the span with tab and then click spacebar. The function that is supplied to `onKeyDown` props will be called. I want the function to not be called.

Comment: the short answer is you can't, but span doesn't react to key down events by default, so what exactly are you trying to prevent from happening?

Comment: My span has contenteditable attribute so when I supply onKeyDown function to the span, the function is called even after I set the span disabled

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your comment @yogi .I don't set contenteditable attribute on the span. However the span is a parent of a complex elements. When I supply onKeyDown function to the span, the function is called even after I set the span disabled. I cant copy my code because it is very complex but I will try to make a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pointerEvents and tabIndex**

The question asks how to prevent keyboard input on a span. However, the code included in the question assigns a value to the element's tabIndex. Setting the tabIndex (or contentEditable) attribute allows the element to receive focus along with keyboard events.

Removing the tabIndex from the span prevents focus and keyboard events, but not mouse events. To prevent both keyboard and mouse events, set pointerEvents to "none". The tabIndex setting doesn't appear to make any difference with a span, but might with an input.

OP notes that pointerEvents "none" did not work and yet in the snippet it does.   The reason is unclear, but perhaps it due to different testing methods.

**React Snippet**

The snippet contains a few span elements with different configurations to try.

```js
const {useState} = React;

ReactDOM.render(
    
      <div>
      
      <span  
        onClick={(e) => log(e)}
        onKeyDown={(e) => log(e)}
        onFocus={(e) => log(e)}
      >
        tabIndex none
      </span>
      
      <span tabIndex={0} 
        onClick={(e) => log(e)}
        onKeyDown={(e) => log(e)}
        onFocus={(e) => log(e)}
      >
        tabIndex 0
      </span>
      
      <span 
        style={{pointerEvents: "none"}}
        onClick={(e) => log(e)}
        onKeyDown={(e) => log(e)}
        onFocus={(e) => log(e)}
      >
        pointer-events none
      </span>

    </div>
  
, document.getElementById("root"));


function log(e) { console.log(e.type) }
```

```css
.pointer-events-none {
  pointer-events: none;
}

span {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: thin dotted blue;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

span:focus {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100px !important; }
```

```html
<p>
click on a span and then type some text using keyboard
</p>

<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution can be to add the `disabled` attribute to the element and then use javascript to limit `eventListeners` to not-disabled elements.

For example:

In html:

```
 <span disabled>Disabled</span>
 <span>Open to events</span>
```

In js:

```
document.querySelector('span:not([disabled=""])').addEventListener("event", handler);
```

But, if elements are being disabled/enabled dynamically, you'd need to add eventListeners after each change in element's state.